# Looking for time and space effective algorithm to convert any integer number into binary value

Tags: javascript, while-loop, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am totally a newbie to programming and this is my first question posted in an online community . I have written a function using JavaScript to convert any integer number into binary value.

```
function number2Binary(inputNumber){
var digitsArray=[];
if(inputNumber === 0 || inputNumber === 1)
{
  return inputNumber;
}
while(inputNumber>0){
  var bit = inputNumber%2;
  inputNumber= parseInt(inputNumber/2);
  digitsArray.push(bit);
}
return digitsArray.reverse().join(" ");  
}
number2Binary(2);
```

I am pretty sure this may not be an optimal solution. Can someone please suggests a better solution for this problem?
Additional question:
1. I used a while loop in my script. How to calculate time complexity for a while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since everything is an Object in JavaScript, numbers are objects too, and because of this you can invoke methods on them.

For numbers there is `Number.prototype.toString` that takes one argument, the base.

If you have your value inside the inputNumber variable, then you can call `inputNumber.toString(2)`.

You can also do the same with hardcoded values: `1.1.toString(2)`.

Be careful if you want to print constant integer because the first dot will be parsed as the decimal point, so you have to write `(1).toString(2)` or `1.0.toString(2)` or just `1..toString(2)` in order to display an hardcoded number.

Answer (score 0):

An simple and fast algorithm

```js
foo = 42
console.log(foo.toString(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string version of the number, you can have

```
Long.toString(42, <base>);
```

so for example,

```
System.out.println(Long.toString(30, 2));
```

produces

```
11110
```

If you want an int array of the number, you can type

```
int[] num = Long.toString(<num>, <base>).chars().map(c->c-'0').toArray();
```

Comment: this code looks more like Java than JavaScript :)
beautiful language Java!